# How to open an image listed in a TilePane on button click

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TilePane that lists images from different directories on my hard disk. I would like, when an image on the TilePane is clicked:

1. To open the folder containing the image,
2. To open the image, for example, with the default program set to open that type of image file.

What I have so far only gives me something like `ImageResources/faviicon.png` when an image is clicked.

Is there any way I can use, for example, `ImageResources/faviicon.png` to do 1. and 2. above? Thank you all.

This is the Class I have:

```
public class TilePaneExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(30);

        String[] imageResources = new String[]{
            //loading images
            "ImageResources/facebook.png",
            "ImageResources/faviicon.png",
            "ImageResources/jquery-logo.png",
            "ImageResources/linkedin_32.png",
            "ImageResources/loading1.png",
            "ImageResources/twitter.png",
            "ImageResources/twitter_32.png",
            "ImageResources/wp.png",};

        VBox vb = new VBox(20);
        Text text4Tile = new Text("Images in TilePane");
        text4Tile.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
        text4Tile.setUnderline(true);
        VBox.setMargin(text4Tile, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));

        //creating Flow Pane
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setHgap(5);
        tilePane.setVgap(5);

        for (final String imageResource : imageResources) {
            Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageResource));
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("You clicked: " + imageResource);
                }
            });
            tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        }

        vb.getChildren().addAll(text4Tile, tilePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll(vb);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TilePane Example");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

***Update:***

Following ***[DarkDarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/darkdarker)'s*** advice, I did this:

```
imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("You clicked: " + imageResource);

                        File f = new File(imageResource);
                        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f.getParentFile());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TilePaneExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I, however, get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: ImageResources doesn't exist.
    at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:209)
    at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (final String imageResource : imageResources) {
    String imagePath = getClass().getResource(imageResource).toExternalForm();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(imagePath));

    imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("You clicked: " + imagePath);
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(imageFile.getParentFile()); // open a folder in explorer 
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(imageFile); // open file with system preferred program
        }
    });
    tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Hi [DarkDarker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/darkdarker). Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I need something like `C:\\tmp`. But with my code above, I get `ImageResources/loading1.png` which cannot be used to do either.

Comment: May be use relative path? "..\\some\\relative\\path"? Or what you problem, why you can not construct path?

Comment: Hi [DarkDarker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/darkdarker). I borrowed your advise and did as I posted in the update section below. I, however, get the above error. Please advise.

Comment: look at path, that you pass in `new File(imagePath)`, You need correctly get it `getClass().getResource(imageResource).toExternalForm();`